# Custom TXmlIniFile method creates an error

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have created this unit containing a class derived from TXmlIniFile:

```
unit PAXMLIniFile;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.IniFiles,
  Xml.XmlDoc,
  Xml.XMLIntf,
  Xml.XMLIniFile;

type
  TMyStandaloneXmlIniFile = class(TXmlIniFile)
  strict private
    FDocument: IXMLDocument;
    FFileName: string;
  public
    constructor Create(const AFileName: string);
    procedure UpdateFile; override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TMyStandaloneXmlIniFile.Create(const AFileName: string);
begin
  if FileExists(AFileName) then
    FDocument := LoadXMLDocument(AFileName)
  else
  begin
    FDocument := NewXMLDocument;
    FDocument.Options := FDocument.Options + [doNodeAutoIndent];
  end;
  if FDocument.DocumentElement = nil then
    FDocument.DocumentElement := FDocument.CreateNode('Sections');
  TCustomIniFile(Self).Create(AFileName); 
  FFileName := AFileName;
  inherited Create(FDocument.DocumentElement);
end;

procedure TMyStandaloneXmlIniFile.UpdateFile;
begin
  FDocument.SaveToFile(FFileName);
end;

end.
```

Now whenever I call the **UpdateFile** method I get an error message "Wrong parameter". What is wrong here?

Here is the test program:

```
program BonkersTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, PAXMLIniFile, Winapi.ActiveX;

var
  MyStandaloneXmlIniFile: TMyStandaloneXmlIniFile;
  MyXmlFile: string;

begin
  try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    MyXmlFile := ChangeFileExt(ParamStr(0), '.xml');
    MyStandaloneXmlIniFile := TMyStandaloneXmlIniFile.Create(MyXmlFile);
    try
      MyStandaloneXmlIniFile.WriteString('Section1', 'Ident1', 'Value1');
      MyStandaloneXmlIniFile.UpdateFile;
    finally
      MyStandaloneXmlIniFile.Free;
    end;
    CoUninitialize;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: `TCustomIniFile(Self).Create(AFileName)` Er, what?!! Followed up with `inherited Create`?! I have simply no idea what that is attempting to achieve.

Comment: It is supposed to use the common TCustomInifile methods to create and read an XML file. Try it out. It is from an idea in the book "Delphi XE2 Foundations"

Comment: `TCustomIniFile(Self).Create(AFileName)` is surely nonsense. Is that your idea, or Chris'? Anyway, I'm not going to dig deeper because there's not a complete program here. It's so easy for you to add that, but I'd have to guess. We must have done this before.

Comment: It is Chris' idea. Have you tried it out?

Comment: It looks utterly bonkers to me. Surely susceptible to implementation changes. I've not tried it out, because I don't have a program to run. You didn't provide one.

Comment: OK, wait a moment...

Comment: Thanks for the update. This program runs successfully for me.

Comment: THIS program also runs successfully for me. However, when using this class in another (larger) program, the `FFileName` variable inside the `TMyStandaloneXmlIniFile.UpdateFile` procedure is always EMPTY. (This produces the error message "Wrong parameter"). I don't understand why it is empty.

Comment: I can't guess what's the problem with your bigger program. I assumed that the program you supplied here would exhibit the fault. If not, then what is its point?

Comment: Well, maybe the class is designed wrongly. Do you see any formal class errors?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not going to spend any more time on this until there's a reproduction. As it stands, this feels like a waste of time. How can we tell that you don't have some other error, unrelated to this code, that only you can see? In my view, this only becomes a real question when the issue is demonstrated.

Comment: I will debug better the bigger program to find the error. Thank you for your time spent on this! - However, I accept your apologies that the class is not bonkers ;-)

Comment: No, I still think that the class is bonkers. I don't know what Chris is thinking of there. However, he does know his stuff, so perhaps he's right and I am wrong, but at the moment, I can see no reason for that to be a sound approach.

Comment: David, do you agree that I delete this post?

Comment: Well, I'd rather it if you could produce a repro, and then we could get it answered.

Comment: In the mean time I've found the error: It was a VERY NASTY and difficult to find bug which randomly made the variable passed to  `TMyStandaloneXmlIniFile.Create` empty. - But now I see the flaw in the class: When the `AFileName` parameter in the constructor is empty then it should raise an error. When you elaborate this in an answer then I will accept the answer as solution.

Comment: Thanks for the kind offer. However, I don't know enough to write an answer. So, I suggest that you either write up your own answer, if you wish, or delete the question. Thanks for your cooperation. I certainly enjoyed your program name!   ;-)

Comment: Don't underestimate yourself. I believe you are a highly professional and very rational expert. I always appreciate your advice!

Comment: Well thanks, but I don't know enough about what Chris has done here to feel confident answering.